# SVG rendering on android browsers

Tags: android, html, css, svg

I'm having an issue for a long time and I can't find a solution.

I have an SVG image as css background on the top left corner of a div. The SVG graphics  should seamlessly merge on the div background, instead produces thin borders around the rendered graphics. It works fine on desktop browsers (tested on Chrome, Firefox and Opera) but it fails on android stock browser, chrome for android, and firefox for android.

Here is a little test case : http://jsfiddle.net/SDJHA/1/
(the SVG code is on the Javascript frame as a comment)

The CSS code is :

```
.cont{ background-color : #7AC943; width : 300px; height : 300px; }

.elementOne{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20width%3D%22100px%22%20height%3D%22100px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20100%20100%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%20100%20100%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20fill%3D%22%237AC943%22%20points%3D%22100%2C100%20100%2C0%200%2C100%20%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
    width : 100px; height: 100px;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color : white;
}
```

The HTML  :
    `<div class="cont"><div class="elementOne"></div></div>`

It may be a bug on the android svg render engine when calculating subpixels... I dont know.

Tested on an Asus Transformer and HTC One.

Any advise ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the lines show up due to compositing of the two parts onto the page. The corner is opaque and tries to cover the larger div, and you get some edge anti-aliasing effects.

I think you might get the same effect if the svg was a png of the same size, assuming it was applied in the same way.

You could probably use a single background svg image that traced the shape you want, as in just use the larger div with a background image.

Comment: Thank you Erik. Yes it seams it's not only a SVG problem. After posting I tried with a gif and got similar result. Nonetheless with SVG the result is more anoying because it creates those edges on the four sides of the background. With a gif, the transparent part merges as it should on the background, the anti-aliasing effect appears only on the filed parts.

Comment: I've decided to used a :before pseudo class absolute positioned at top:-1px and left:-1px so the blank edges stays on top of a white part of my layout. I'm going to wait to see if another answer emerges before marking this post answered. I consider this a bug, but I don't know where I should file it (chrome, firefox or android developer forum ? ).